# Eureka: How to push a VC from a PushRow without Segue

Tags: swift, eureka-forms

I am using Eureka to do a settingsVC and I am having trouble pushing a newVC from a pushRow. **Note that I do not use storyboard**

My setup is relatively simple, and my newVC is a simple UIViewController with some uitextfields and labels. Because I do not use storyboard, I can't seem to use performSegues and `$0.presentationMode = .segueName(segueName: "RowsExampleViewControllerSegue", onDismiss: nil)`

I have also reviewed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39448586/how-to-present-a-viewcontroller-using-a-row-in-eureka-forms) but this post is relatively far fetched for my application.

My implementation so far as such:

```
class AccountsViewController: FormViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        form +++ Section("Profile")

            <<< PushRow<String>() { row in
                row.title = "Edit phone number"
                row.value = "+61 12345678"
                }.onCellSelection({ (cell, row) in
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ChangePhoneNumberViewController(), animated: true)
            })
```

The above approach pushes the VC twice.

My reason for wanting to adopt pushRow is because I want it to adopt the pushRow aesthetic looks, like the image attached. I have also considered exploring ButtonRow but the UI/UX is just not right. Moving ahead I would also need to use protocols to bring the new "phoneNumber" to the AccountsViewController.

[image]

EDIT:

Attempted the following code but produces the error message.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same error, you can try to include the return type and also the argument label `builder` to the callback:

```
row.presentationMode = PresentationMode.show(
                controllerProvider: ControllerProvider.callback(builder: { () -> UIViewController in
                    return AcknowListViewController()
                }),
                onDismiss: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to set the presentation mode like this:

```
presentationMode = PresentationMode.show(
    controllerProvider: ControllerProvider.callback(
        {return ChangePhoneNumberViewController()}
    ), onDismiss: nil)
```

`ControllerProvider.callback` lets you provide a VC by returning one from a closure, instead of from a nib file or storyboard.

Comment: I can't seem to build the above code. Pls see my edits